# Unable to run SOAP client-server on separate well connected machines

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am having a soap client-server application which runs well on the same machine. Now i want to separate the server-client entities on two different machines. Have done the proper IIS configurations - both the machines are pingable - but the following error occurs at the client side. 209.2.208.160:51645 is the server socket.

There was no endpoint listening at http://209.2.208.160:51645/Service1.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For an initial troubleshooting step, I suggest going to the server and running the **netstat** command to verify that it is listening on port 51645.  If it is not, confirm your IIS port settings on the server.  MS KB tip on how to view and change these settings for various IIS versions - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605.

If the server is listening on port 51645, check to make sure that a firewall is not blocking your incoming client connection on that port - that would explain why your service call works with everything on one machine.